# [ROS2][Nav2] Nav2 Planner Metrics

Tags: navigation, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am new to ROS and I don't know if this is the right place to ask about this.
I did research but I couldn't find anything about how to calculate some planner metrics.

I would like to run a wide variety of planners SmacPlanner, A*, Hybrid-A* and varying some parameters while measuring the time to obtain the global path and its length. For now, I'm clueless about how to do it.

Additionally, I would like to set the initial pose and the goal pose programmatically so I can guarantee that the start and final poses are always the same. I do not have this precision using rviz commands. I tried publishing to the topic /initialpose with the following command but without success.

ros2 topic pub -1 /initialpose  geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped '{ header: {stamp: {sec: 0, nanosec: 0}, frame_id: "map"}, pose: { pose: {position: {x: 10, y: 10.0, z: 00.0}, orientation: {w: 0.1}}, } }'
Said that I have the following questions:

Is there a topic that I can subscribe in order to get those metrics (path length and average time to compute global path)?
Is the initialpose the correct topic to publish this pose? Which topic can I use to publish the goal pose? I tried the /goal_pose but also without success.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381475/%5Bros2%5D%5Bnav2%5D-nav2-planner-metrics/) by [PHFP](https://answers.ros.org/users/73377/phfp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2021-06-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To prod you in the right direction, I think you want to use action calls to set the goal pose. `ros2 action send_goal /compute_path_to_pose nav2_msgs/action/ComputePathToPose ...` seems like what you want. I am not aware of metrics on planning time or path length that are readily available so you may want to dig through the source a bit to see what information is computed already. If you can't find anything, the [path message](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Path.html) that gets published has a list of waypoints that you could use to approximate path length. Assuming its [header](http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Header.html) is filled out, you should also have access to the timestamp, which you could use to back out how long the planner took.

---

Originally posted by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) with karma: 1567 on 2021-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0